# How Insert a columns of unpartitoned table into a partitioned table in Hive?

Tags: hive

A table 'A'is there which is partitioned. The another table 'B' is not partitioned . How to insert the values of B into A? Will error be thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can insert from a non-partitioned table to a partitioned table.  You will either have to define the partition you want to insert into or have Hive do it dynamically.

For example, to dynamically insert into partitions, you could run something similar to:

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
INSERT INTO TABLE A PARTITION (partition) SELECT col1, col2, ..., colN, partition FROM B WHERE .... ;
```

More information regarding Hive Partitions with dynamic inserts can be found here : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions.  Take note, the last column in your SELECT is what is used for the partition insert.  Another thing to note is that you need the number of columns to match between the two tables, otherwise you will have to fill in NULLs.